# Setup testcontainers postgres with spring boot (maven) and spock

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spock, testcontainers

I'm trying to setup Testcontainers with spring boot application to create integration tests.
I'm using PostgreSQL database, Spock framework for tests and Maven as a build system.

I did read quite a few blog posts but everyone seems to configure this setup in a different way.
I'm really confused as I thought that it will be quite straightforward task.

I have this configuration right now:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer
import org.testcontainers.spock.Testcontainers
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class TransactionRepositoryTest extends Specification {

    private static final String POSTGRES_IMAGE = "postgres:latest"
    private static final String POSTGRES_DB = "assignment-test"
    private static final String POSTGRES_USER = "postgres"
    private static final String POSTGRES_PASSWORD = "postgrespass"

    @Shared
    static PostgreSQLContainer postgresql = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(POSTGRES_IMAGE))
            .withDatabaseName(POSTGRES_DB)
            .withUsername(POSTGRES_USER)
            .withPassword(POSTGRES_PASSWORD)

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerPgProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgresql::getJdbcUrl)
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgresql::getUsername)
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgresql::getPassword)
    }
  
    // some tests
}
```

But when I'm running my test I'm getting this error:

(docker is running)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4f59a516 testClass = com.transactionsassignment.integration.transaction.TransactionRepositoryTest, locations = [], classes = [com.transactionsassignment.TransactionsAssignmentApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@3e84448c, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7e5afaa6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@73e22a3d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@306e95ec, org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@66ed20ff, org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@19902e80], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:56)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptInitializerMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:156)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.transactionsassignment.TransactionsAssignmentApplication]: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
```

This is my maven:

```xml
  <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.version>3.1.0</maven.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.6.0</postgresql.version>
        <gmavenplus.version>3.0.0</gmavenplus.version>
        <groovy.version>4.0.12</groovy.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.18.3</testcontainers.version>
        <spock.version>2.4-M1-groovy-4.0</spock.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gmavenplus.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I think that this is problem with some mismatching dependency?

Please help me to get  rid of this error and setup this configuration the right way.

Comment: `spring.test.database.replace=NONE` (property/annotation)!? (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.html)

Comment: Instead of the `testcontainers-spock` integration, start the container manually using the `start()` method in `registerPgProperties()` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your issue:

```java
static PostgreSQLContainer postgresql = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(POSTGRES_IMAGE))
        .withDatabaseName(POSTGRES_DB)
        .withUsername(POSTGRES_USER)
        .withPassword(POSTGRES_PASSWORD)

@Shared
PostgreSQLContainer postgresqlContainer = postgresql

@DynamicPropertySource
static void registerPgProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgresql::getJdbcUrl)
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgresql::getUsername)
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgresql::getPassword)
}
```

`@Shared` doesn't initialize static fields.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that behavior of @Shared ;/ This works now!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use the [Testcontainers JDBC integration](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/).

Just set your `spring.datasource.url` to something like this `jdbc:tc:postgresql:9.6.8:///databasename` and testcontainers will manage the docker container transparently. There is no need to mess with users/password or manually managing the container.

Comment: As an alternative approach, that also works well.

Comment: this is great, just 2 rows of config and voila

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize testcontainer before starting Spring in `ApplicationContextInitializer`:

```kotlin
class PostgresTestContainersInitializer :
    ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    override fun initialize(applicationContext: ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
        val postgresSqlContainer = PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>("postgres:15.4")

        postgresSqlContainer.start()

        // should shut down container on context close
        applicationContext.beanFactory.registerSingleton("postgresSqlContainer", postgresSqlContainer)

        TestPropertyValues.of(
            mapOf(
                "spring.datasource.url" to postgresSqlContainer.jdbcUrl,
                "spring.datasource.username" to postgresSqlContainer.username,
                "spring.datasource.password" to postgresSqlContainer.password,
            )
        ).applyTo(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

And just annotate your test like:

```kotlin
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = [PostgresTestContainersInitializer::class])
```

I described benefits of this approach here:
https://brightinventions.pl/blog/spring-tests-with-testcontainers/